# All Fields of Django Model Entry Comma Separated

Tags: python, django

The code in the two if-blocks smells to violate DRY. How can it be written more generic?

```
selected_class = eval(choice)            # bad  (see comments)
selected_class = getattr(models, choice) # good (see comments)
records = selected_class.objects.all()
if (choice == 'Treatment'):
    for record in records:
        response.write(str(record.id) + ',' + str(record.available_hours) + '\n')
if (choice == 'Patient'):
    for record in records:
        response.write(str(record.id) + ',' + record.first_name + '\n')
```

I could write in each model (Treatment and Patient) a method 'make_csv'. But, there must be a better way.

Comment: Incidentally, why are you doing `eval(choice)`?

Comment: Choice is a string. But I do need a class (Patient, Treatment). `eval(choice)` returns the class.

Comment: I realize that, but usually there's a way to do it that doesn't use `eval`. Where is your string coming from? Actually, In your case we don't even need to know that, you could just `import models` and then `getattr(models, choice)`. `eval` is potentially dangerous, particularly when it is being applied to a "choice".

Comment: `choice` comes from a `ChoiceField` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) in a form: `choice = form.data['choice']`.

Comment: That's where `eval` can become dangerous. Are you validating that the `choice` is what it should be ('Treatment' or 'Patient')? If not, it's possible that someone could `POST` code to that form and have it run on the server. In any case, if you avoided `eval` you wouldn't have that concern.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
for record in records:
    if choice == 'Treatment':
        item = str(record.available_hours)
    elif choice == 'Patient':
        item = record.first_name
    response.write('{},{}\n'.format(record.id, item))
```

Or, if you want a slightly more complex solution that avoids repeating the `if`:

```
choices_dict = {
    'Treatment': 'available_hours',
    'Patient': 'first_name',
}

record_field = choices_dict[choice]

for record in records:
    item = getattr(record, record_field) 
    response.write('{},{}\n'.format(record.id, item))
```

It's also more flexible in case you may want to change or add options to `choices_dict`, but that may not be relevant.